# Sticky dropdown navbar disappears when responsive on small screen

Tags: css, navbar, dropdown, responsive, sticky

There was a similar question, based on the same w3school codes here
[Dropdown navigation bar vs sticky navigation bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50493062/dropdown-navigation-bar-vs-sticky-navigation-bar) asked and answered but I need a little more functionality.

On Desktop or wide screen:
The navbar is sticky when page is scrolled. The dropdown menu works. Happy with that.

On Mobile or narrow screen (when media queries kick in):
The sticky feature still works. However, navbar disappears when hamburger menu is clicked. No dropdown either. Navbar reappears and hamburger becomes functional when page is scrolled back to top.

I spent a good part of the day trying with various combinations in html and css but none seem to work. I suspect the JS myFunction() is the culprit but, as a relative newbie, I do not know enough JS to solve the problem.

Codepen can be viewed here https://codepen.io/harlequin8/pen/bxERNb/

Please help. Thank you

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}

window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction2()
};

var navbar = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction2() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky")
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  /*vertical align with .topnav a, from 14px 16px*/
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  /* absolute;
        ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46535480/position-fixed-ruins-the-dropdown-menu-in-css-webpage */
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* stocky part begin */

.header {
  padding: 0 16px;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}


/* sticky part end  */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child),
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: .05px solid white;
    /* dropdown separation line */
  }
  .topnav.responsive a:nth-child(5) {
    border-top: .05px solid white;
  }
  /* dropdown separation line */
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="w3_responsive_topnav.html">News</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Products
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="w3_sticky.html">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#">&#9776;</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
  <p>The navbar will stck to the top when you reach its scroll position</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut nesciunt repellendus doloremque deleniti illo, nam saepe repellat, optio tempore praesentium qui quo debitis vitae quisquam delectus accusantium pariatur in.
    Praesentium eius id magnam laudantium, ducimus. Dolor culpa incidunt numquam fuga deserunt necessitatibus assumenda pariatur, quod unde, velit neque sit earum.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut nesciunt repellendus doloremque deleniti illo, nam saepe repellat, optio tempore praesentium qui quo debitis vitae quisquam delectus accusantium pariatur in.
    Praesentium eius id magnam laudantium, ducimus. Dolor culpa incidunt numquam fuga deserunt necessitatibus assumenda pariatur, quod unde, velit neque sit earum.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut nesciunt repellendus doloremque deleniti illo, nam saepe repellat, optio tempore praesentium qui quo debitis vitae quisquam delectus accusantium pariatur in.
    Praesentium eius id magnam laudantium, ducimus. Dolor culpa incidunt numquam fuga deserunt necessitatibus assumenda pariatur, quod unde, velit neque sit earum.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut nesciunt repellendus doloremque deleniti illo, nam saepe repellat, optio tempore praesentium qui quo debitis vitae quisquam delectus accusantium pariatur in.
    Praesentium eius id magnam laudantium, ducimus. Dolor culpa incidunt numquam fuga deserunt necessitatibus assumenda pariatur, quod unde, velit neque sit earum.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut nesciunt repellendus doloremque deleniti illo, nam saepe repellat, optio tempore praesentium qui quo debitis vitae quisquam delectus accusantium pariatur in.
    Praesentium eius id magnam laudantium, ducimus. Dolor culpa incidunt numquam fuga deserunt necessitatibus assumenda pariatur, quod unde, velit neque sit earum.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut nesciunt repellendus doloremque deleniti illo, nam saepe repellat, optio tempore praesentium qui quo debitis vitae quisquam delectus accusantium pariatur in.
    Praesentium eius id magnam laudantium, ducimus. Dolor culpa incidunt numquam fuga deserunt necessitatibus assumenda pariatur, quod unde, velit neque sit earum.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut nesciunt repellendus doloremque deleniti illo, nam saepe repellat, optio tempore praesentium qui quo debitis vitae quisquam delectus accusantium pariatur in.
    Praesentium eius id magnam laudantium, ducimus. Dolor culpa incidunt numquam fuga deserunt necessitatibus assumenda pariatur, quod unde, velit neque sit earum.</p>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is one of **[specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)**. Your `.sticky` class correctly adds `position: fixed` to keep your navbar in place for the expanded responsive menu... though the `.topnav.responsive` selector adds `position: relative` with more specificity.

To correct this, I would recommend creating a new class inside of your media query to add `position:fixed` back, whilst giving more specificity:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive.sticky {
    position: fixed;
  }
}
```

This can be seen in the following:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}

window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction2()
};

var navbar = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction2() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky")
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  /*vertical align with .topnav a, from 14px 16px*/
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  /* absolute;
        ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46535480/position-fixed-ruins-the-dropdown-menu-in-css-webpage */
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* stocky part begin */

.header {
  padding: 0 16px;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}


/* sticky part end  */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child),
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive.sticky {
    position: fixed;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: .05px solid white;
    /* dropdown separation line */
  }
  .topnav.responsive a:nth-child(5) {
    border-top: .05px solid white;
  }
  /* dropdown separation line */
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="w3_responsive_topnav.html">News</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Products
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="w3_sticky.html">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#">&#9776;</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
  <p>The navbar will stck to the top when you reach its scroll position</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut nesciunt repellendus doloremque deleniti illo, nam saepe repellat, optio tempore praesentium qui quo debitis vitae quisquam delectus accusantium pariatur in.
    Praesentium eius id magnam laudantium, ducimus. Dolor culpa incidunt numquam fuga deserunt necessitatibus assumenda pariatur, quod unde, velit neque sit earum.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut nesciunt repellendus doloremque deleniti illo, nam saepe repellat, optio tempore praesentium qui quo debitis vitae quisquam delectus accusantium pariatur in.
    Praesentium eius id magnam laudantium, ducimus. Dolor culpa incidunt numquam fuga deserunt necessitatibus assumenda pariatur, quod unde, velit neque sit earum.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut nesciunt repellendus doloremque deleniti illo, nam saepe repellat, optio tempore praesentium qui quo debitis vitae quisquam delectus accusantium pariatur in.
    Praesentium eius id magnam laudantium, ducimus. Dolor culpa incidunt numquam fuga deserunt necessitatibus assumenda pariatur, quod unde, velit neque sit earum.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut nesciunt repellendus doloremque deleniti illo, nam saepe repellat, optio tempore praesentium qui quo debitis vitae quisquam delectus accusantium pariatur in.
    Praesentium eius id magnam laudantium, ducimus. Dolor culpa incidunt numquam fuga deserunt necessitatibus assumenda pariatur, quod unde, velit neque sit earum.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut nesciunt repellendus doloremque deleniti illo, nam saepe repellat, optio tempore praesentium qui quo debitis vitae quisquam delectus accusantium pariatur in.
    Praesentium eius id magnam laudantium, ducimus. Dolor culpa incidunt numquam fuga deserunt necessitatibus assumenda pariatur, quod unde, velit neque sit earum.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut nesciunt repellendus doloremque deleniti illo, nam saepe repellat, optio tempore praesentium qui quo debitis vitae quisquam delectus accusantium pariatur in.
    Praesentium eius id magnam laudantium, ducimus. Dolor culpa incidunt numquam fuga deserunt necessitatibus assumenda pariatur, quod unde, velit neque sit earum.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut nesciunt repellendus doloremque deleniti illo, nam saepe repellat, optio tempore praesentium qui quo debitis vitae quisquam delectus accusantium pariatur in.
    Praesentium eius id magnam laudantium, ducimus. Dolor culpa incidunt numquam fuga deserunt necessitatibus assumenda pariatur, quod unde, velit neque sit earum.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried your code in another pen but could get it to work as intended. https://codepen.io/harlequin8/pen/dqMppx. In sticky mode, navbar still disappears on clicking hamburger icon. What am I doing wrong? Meanwhile, I will look further into specificity.

Comment: I tried a quick and dirty hack (despite the warning of misuse) from the Speficity article  '.topnav.responsive.sticky {
    position: fixed !important;
  }' but this did not work either.